# Can I use Maven repository manager outside of Maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, aether

I already asked in [Maven User List](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/can-I-use-Maven-repository-manager-outside-of-Maven-tt3555990.html), let me duplicate here.

I'm trying to create an application that will download and use Maven 
artifacts outside of Maven. I think that in this case the smartest way would 
be to use Maven already existing classes. Can anyone help me with a hint 
where to look for?

Would be nice to make it working this way:

```
Repository rep = new Repository("~/.m2"); 
Artifact artifact = new Artifact("com.example", "foo", "1.0"); 
String path = rep.resolve(artifact); 
assert path.equals("~/.m2/repository/com/example/foo/1.0/foo.jar");
```

I'm using Maven 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aether](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/AETHER/Home) does exactly what I need.

edit: A few weeks ago I created an open source tool that simplifies the interaction with Aether: [jcabi-aether](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aether/). Now it is as simple as (in maven plugin):

```
File repo = this.session.getLocalRepository().getBasedir();
Collection<Artifact> deps = new Aether(this.getProject(), repo).resolve(
  new DefaultArtifact("junit", "junit-dep", "", "jar", "4.10"),
  JavaScopes.RUNTIME
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to see if it fits your needs?