# How to programmatically retrieve artifacts' jars from Maven in order to perform search inside them?

Tags: maven, jar, artifact

How to programmatically retrieve artifacts' jars from Maven in order to perform search inside them? Any ideas or some useful API?

Comment: So I assume you want to download the source code? Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059431/get-source-jars-from-maven-repository

Comment: From [Can I use Maven repository manager outside of Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296271): Use [Aether](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/AETHER/Home) if you want to benefit from Maven dependency resolution mechanizm.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer uses ivy to download source jars so that they can be compiled

[Maven compile a source jar dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432549/maven-compile-a-source-jar-dependency/7436786#7436786)

You didn't specify what you were searching for. Sounds like you'll possibly need a custom plug-in if you continue with a Maven solution.